# how to set -A flag in screenrc

Tags: command-line, gnu-screen, screenrc

The screen man says

> ‘-A’
>   Adapt the sizes of all windows to the size of the display. By
>   default, screen may try to restore its old window sizes when attaching
>   to resizable terminals (those with ‘WS’ in their descriptions, e.g.
>   suncmd or some varieties of xterm).

This works when you start off a screen with the -A flag. But, how do I set it in screenrc so that all my screen sessions get it by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fit

Change  the  window  size to the size of the current region. This command is needed
because screen doesn't adapt the window size automatically if the  window  is  dis-
played more than once.
```

Default key binding for `fit` is C-a F.